# Задать цикл в условиях

Tags: python-3.x

```
pattern1 = '<span(.*?)</span>'
res = re.findall(pattern1, textdata)
resultlist = []
for z in range(len(res)):
    if 'style=font-weight:bold' in res[z]:
        is_bold = True
    elif 'uclass_24' in res[z]:
        is_bold = True
    elif 'uclass_48' in res[z]:
        is_bold = True
    elif 'uclass_72' in res[z]:
        is_bold = True
    elif 'uclass_96' in res[z]:
        is_bold = True
    else:
        is_bold = False
    resultlist.append(is_bold)
data['is_bold'] = resultlist
resultlist.count(True)
```

Необходимо этот код упростить с помощью цикла (там где elif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pattern1 = '<span(.*?)</span>'
res = re.findall(pattern1, textdata)
resultlist = []
for z in range(len(res)):
    if 'style=font-weight:bold' in res[z]:
        is_bold = True
    elif [ True for i in [ 'uclass_24', 'uclass_48', 'uclass_72', 'uclass_96'] if i in res[z]]:
        is_bold = True
    else:
        is_bold = False
    resultlist.append(is_bold)
data['is_bold'] = resultlist
resultlist.count(True)
```

---

Попробуйте так:

```
# ...
resultlist = []
listClass = ['style=font-weight:bold', 'uclass_24', 'uclass_48', 'uclass_72', 'uclass_96',]
for z in range(len(res)):
    is_bold = False
    for i in listClass:
        if i in res[z]:
            is_bold = True
            break
    resultlist.append(is_bold)  
# ...
```

Comment: что если таких 'uclass' будет не 4, а во много раз больше, тогда обычная запись будет затратной по времени. Там uclass идет с шагом 24, можно ли как то через цикл записать?

Comment: ///////////@S. Nick

Comment: Добавил, попробуйте